# "Send" button popup not appearing correctly

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, send

I'm using the Facebook Like/Send buttons along with dynamically generated HTML (loaded via AJAX requests). I've found that even though the *Send* button works fine when the element exists on page load, dynamically created Send buttons aren't working correctly. Clicking the button activates it and the button greys out, but the popup doesn't appear.

Here is a demonstration of what is happening: http://jsfiddle.net/Daniel15/VxpSj/

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I can confirm the problem from your fiddle.

```
function addLikeButton()
{
    // […]
    FB.XFBML.parse(newEl);
    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(newEl);
}
```

For some reason, this seems to be “the wrong way around”. *Reverse* the order of these two lines – put the new element into the DOM *first* and let FB.XFBML.parse parse it *afterwards*, then (from my test with your fiddle) it seems to work in the desired way.

Comment: Thank you! Just tested this with my actual code and it seems to fix it. :)